# The 'Asyncio' event loop isn't working [Discord PY]

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I've started to try coding a discord bot but it was cut short when setting a prefix and events wouldn't work. It just displays an error message that says 'the command "hello" can not be found'.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="*" ,status=discord.Status.idle, activity=discord.Game("Starting up..."))

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.do_not_disturb, activity=discord.Game("Preparing Puzzle Event"))
    print("Bot is running.")
@client.event
async def hello(ctx):
  await ctx.send("Hi")

client.run('[The token]')
```

I know that the token is valid as I've ran it before without assigning a prefix and using 'async'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@client.event
async def hello(ctx):
  await ctx.send("Hi")
```

This won't work because `hello` is not a built-in event. See: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord-api-events

What you want is a command probably

```
@client.command()
async def hello(ctx):
  await ctx.send("Hi")
```

This registers the bot to respond to the command `.hello` assuming `.` is your prefix